# properly install firefox beta (fedora)

Tags: fedora, software-installation, firefox

I want to install [firefox desktop beta](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/#product-desktop-beta) in my fedora, for that I have dl the `.tar.bz2` in the official site.

I already have a firefox version installed via `dnf` but this is the *normal* version. Now I want to have both, with auto update for the beta version if possible.

I don't want to use flatpack nor snap because I want to understand how this kind of *installion* works (specially for activating the auto update for the beta version).

I have the *normal* version on `~/.mozilla/` and the *beta* version works well when I run the `firefox` file given by the `.tar.bz2`.

My plans is to to put the content of the `.tar.bz2` into `~/.mozilla/beta/` and create a `desktop` file pointing to the right bin (`~/.mozilla/beta/firefox`).

Another question : I have two files into the `.tar.bz2` which start (both) the program (`firefox` & `firefox-bin`), what is the difference between them ?

Comment: 1. dot files and directories at home are normally configuration files, not executables files
2. Applications which are not part of a distro are normally installed in `/opt`, e.g. `/opt/firefox`

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification @ArtemS.Tashkinov. In my `opt` i have some app but not all the app installed by the `dnf` command or `faltpack` or `snap`. The destination folder of each app is set by the author of the package or by the installation manager (dnf, ...) ?